# how trivial arithmetics with null-coalescing behaves

Tags: c#

I have a method

```
int? Foo(int? a, int? b)
{
    return a ?? 0 + b ?? 0;
}
```

I was surprised that result of `Foo(12, 4)` is 12, although I was expecting 16.

I know that null-coalescing purifies type from nullabilty. So, I thought, maybe nullable types don't add up with structures. But expression `(int?) 12 + (int) 4` returns expected 16.

Looks like only expression with coalescing behaves in unobvious way: `(int?) 12 ?? 0 + (int) 4` gives 12.

Why don't each of the examples above return 16?

Comment: null coalescing has a lower [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) than addition  change it to `(a ?? 0) + (b ?? 0)`

Comment: Well, now it is obvious indeed, that i should've noticed the precedence of operations. Also, it is not actually obvious on SO how to choose correct answer if almost all of them are pretty exact.

Comment: Just make extension methods for AddOrDefault then you can chain with ?. Instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACh8BmAAiJoGEaBvCm9mgSwDsAXAfhoAxCBAAUPATQCGaLn0HAAlBVbkOdAOwya/QQAYa2GsF0GA3BQC+1oA==) to see how your code behaves under the hood. It doesn't perform any addition operations

```cs
private int? Foo(int? a, int? b)
{
    int? num = a;
    int valueOrDefault;
    if (!num.HasValue)
    {
        int? num2 = b;
        int? num3 = num2.HasValue ? new int?(num2.GetValueOrDefault()) : null;
        valueOrDefault = num3.GetValueOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        valueOrDefault = num.GetValueOrDefault();
    }
    return valueOrDefault;
}
```

Adding a braces to `return (a ?? 0) + (b ?? 0);` due to [lower precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) of `??` operator will solve the situation. Under the hood it'll be

```cs
private int? Foo(int? a, int? b)
{
    return a.GetValueOrDefault() + b.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Although all answers are correct, i mark this as the right one because of the reference to pretty cool tool for inspection of all kinds of decompiled code. And because this acually shows what instructions lay beneath this code.

Answer (score 3):

You should use parenthesis, otherwise it is computed uncorrectly:

```
int? Foo(int? a, int? b)
{
    return (a ?? 0) + (b ?? 0);
}
```

Your version computes the following:

```
int? Foo(int? a, int? b)
{
    return a ?? ((0 + b ) ?? 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You method behaves like this

```
int? Foo(int? a, int? b)
{
    if (a == null)
    {
        int? temp = 0 + b;              
        if (temp == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return temp;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return a;
    }
}
```

to make it behave like you expect, you have to set brackets

```
int? Foo(int? a, int? b)
{
    return (a ?? 0) + (b ?? 0);
}
```

Comment: Actually it would put the addition into a temp variable.

Answer (score 1):

### Reason for the answer **12**

```
return a ?? 0 + b ?? 0;
```

is interpreted as

```
return a ?? ((0 + b) ?? 0);
```

as a result

```
return 12 ?? ((0 + 4) ?? 0)  => 12
```

[Reference: Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)

**important note**

> Right-associative operators are evaluated in order from right to left. The assignment operators, the null-coalescing operators, and the conditional operator ?: are right-associative.

Comment: No, It's `a ?? (0+b) ?? 0`

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was reading that. I am going to modify it